# How to display Session data and How to save session data to corresponding database tables in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to display the students added, how to do this and I want to save all the students into database table `students`. And one more table called order which has relation with the the student domain class as below

```
class Order extends AppModel { 
    var $name="Order"; 
    var $belongsTo = array( 
        'Student' => array( 
            'className' =>'Student', 
            'foreignKey' => 'StudentId'
        )
    );
}

class Student extends AppModel { 
    var $name='Student'; 
    var $hasOne = array( 
        'Order' => array( 
            'className' => 'Order', 
            'foreignKey' => 'StudentId'
        )
    );
}
```

and I have created relation in database that foreign key `studentId` of order table references `Id` column of `Student` table. So now how to save both associated models?

Comment: what has the session got to do with this question? You should also have a look at this link : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo This explains how to do what you're attempting

Answer (score 0):

you must pass a correct formatted data to `save` method of your model.

data format is something like

```
$data = array('Modelname' => array(
                   'col1'=>'val1',
                   'col1'=>'val2' )
             );
```